# Дополнение репозитория GitHub новым кодом

Tags: github

В общем такая ситуация.Написал код комитнул синхронизовал.Теперь то что было стёр и написал новое.Теперь если его заново комитить, то удалится предыдущее.А мне нужно что бы в репозиторие и то, и то было(слилось воедино так сказать).Вариант закоментировать не подходит.Пользуюсь плагином для Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

Сделай

```
git stash
```

Что это можно почитать здесь 
http://stepansuvorov.com/blog/2012/11/git-stash-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB/

потом создай ветку и перейди в нее.

```
git checkout -b NAME_BRANCH
```

После примени спрятанные изменения

```
git stash apply
```

Добавь в комит их

```
git add .
```

и сделай комит.

```
git commit -m "custom text"
```

После  этого можно перейти назад на первую ветку и делать

```
git merge NAME_BRANCH
```